# How to empty Amazon MSSQL RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, rds

A script malfunctioned over night and it added millions of records in our database and as a result we ran out of storage. After I deleted the table and the script, Amazon RDS still shows the database as full.

I don't have any options available from the drop down menus except Delete.

Anyone had to go through this before and what were the steps to fix the issue?

Comment: Is it actually full though or is it just the console reporting that it is full?

Comment: @user602525 it was full and then I deleted a huge table as mentioned above but the console it is still showing that I only have 9MB left on it.

Comment: But when you say "it" is still showing that you only have 9MB left, what do you mean by "it?" The AWS RDS console or can you actually see stats by connecting to the sql server?

Comment: @user602525 apologies, the AWS RDS

Comment: Maybe the console just is out of date?

Comment: @user602525 I have tried to log out of the console and wait for an hour but it is still showing the same values.

Comment: Maybe the console using size on disk. Did you try shrinking the database?

Comment: @Peter I did had to shrink tempdb with the help of amanzon

Answer (score 0):

The tempdb had to go through shrinking and now everything is back to normal.